# Excel formula to search two columns for unique value in one column and fixed value in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Got status codes in column H (BE, BK, TR, MO) and Serial numbers in column N. My aim is to find rows with duplicate Serial numbers, and mark them out With "unik" on 1 of them and "duplikate" on similar cells/rows BUT at the same time do this only when status codes in H is either "BK" or "BE".

This is my attempt so far:

```
=IF(AND((COUNTIF($N$2:$N132,$N132)=1)+0,OR($H$2:$H132="BK",$H$2:$H132="BE")),"bk-be_unik","bk-be_duplikat")
```

It Works, but only when status code "BE" or "BK" is found at the first row holding a duplicate Serial number. 
If there are 6 rows holding Serial number "999", and the first row is status code like "MO", the formula give me "duplicate" on all 6 rows.

Is there a way to do this so that it will work no matter where the status code I'm searching for is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this

[image]

In `A2` use formula:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$4000,N2,$H$2:$H$4000,{"BK","BE"}))>1,IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N2,N2,$H$2:$H2,{"BK","BE"}))=1,"unik","duplikate"),"")
```

Reversed order:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$4000,N2,$H$2:$H$4000,{"BK","BE"}))>1,IF(SUM(COUNTIFS($N2:$N$4000,N2,$H2:$H$4000,{"BK","BE"}))=1,"unik","duplikate"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to match serial numbers in column N when either "BK" or "BE" is in the same row in column H.

```
=IF(sumproduct(COUNTIFs($N$2:$N132, $N132, $H$2:$H132, {"BK", "BE"}))=1, "bk-be_unik", "bk-be_duplikat")
```

Comment: I tested it and it works as expected. I will grant you that you need to cover other conditions than `=1` but neither your sample formula nor your narrative covers any other scenarios and I was reluctant to start making guesses.

Comment: Sorry, I had an unintentional edit, I rolled-back the answer.